# Restify dynamic routes based on database result

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, restify

I am trying to create specific routing rules for my application.

However, I would like those rules to be generic based on the content of a table in a database.

This means that sometimes some of the routings may be inserted or removed in the restify service depending on the database rules.

I was looking for a solution, but I cannot find anything, here is an example of my code:

```
server.put('/logging/create', function(req, res, next){
    return next(); 
});

server.delete('/logging/delete', function(req, res, next){
    return next(); 
});

server.post('/logging/update', function(req, res, next){
    return next(); 
});
```

What I want to achieve is to add/remove specific requests on the fly without restarting the node js script. What I have is an array that contains all the rules. An example of a rule would be :

```
{
   "name":"/logging/create",
   "method":"put",
   "status":"active"
},
{
   "name":"/logging/delete",
   "method":"delete",
   "status":"inactive"
},
{
   "name":"/logging/update",
   "method":"post",
   "status":"active"
}
```

The only thing I want is to add/remove routes on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the dynamic data and suppose you have that in an array -

```
var ruleData = .... // This is your rules array
```

Now whenever a request comes to any of the dynamic routes, you could check in the `ruleData` array if that route is *active* or *inactive*. If the route is *active* then forward the request and if its *inactive* then return a 404 status code.

Example -

```
server.put('/logging/create', function(req, res, next){
    // checking if rule for this path exists and is active
    if(ruleData.find(rule => rule.name == req.path() && rule.status == 'active') != null)
        next();
    else
        res.send(404, {error: 'This route does not exist'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something more on the lines of arguments being part of the routes.

you can accept parameters as part of the routes to set context.

for eg.:
`server.get('/logging/:action', loggingHandler);`

you can then use req.params.action in loggingHandler and compare against a list of actions.

```
function listingPaged(req, res, next) {
    switch (req.params.action) {
        case "create":
                      console.log("create log");
                      break;
        case "delete":
                      console.log("delete log");
                      break;
        case "update":
                      console.log("update log");
                      break;
        default:
                console.log("empty");
                break;

       }
       next();
 }
```

You can also have more dynamic routes by accepting more parameters as a part of your route.

eg.: 
`server.get('/list/userdetails/:userid/:about', userDetailsHandler);`